# Trying to create a structured array Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, nullpointerexception

I'd like to be able to create something like this:

```
int points = 250;

public class point {

    float x, y;

}

point[] p = new point[points];

// constructor
public JavaMain() {

    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < points; i++) {

        int tx = r.nextInt(640) + 1;
        int ty = r.nextInt(480) + 1;

        p[i].x = (float)tx;
        p[i].y = (float)ty;

    }
}
```

The problem is that this throws up a `NullPointerException` when trying to assign a value to `p[i].x` or `p[i].y`

This is my first day on Java and have done some research via Google and StackOverflow but not uncovered anything that gets to the heart of the problem.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You need to initialize the elements in array as well not just array reference

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: the answer below answers it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` exception you are getting is caused by this line:

```
p[i].x = (float)tx;
```

where you are trying to access the `x` attribute of the object stored inside the `p` array at position `i`, but this element (or any other element inside this array) has not been set yet and is equal to null.

To fix this, add this line above the mentioned line:

```
p[i] = new point();
```

Comment: Seems strange to do it that way. I thought it would allocate space for the entire array on the initial declaration like in other object oriented languages.

Comment: Since `point` is not a primitive type the compiler is unable to figure out how to initialize an array of such type. Out of curiosity, in which object oriented language it works differently?

Comment: In C++ once you have created the structure of `point` and created and array `point p[100]` there is no need to initialise each element in the array, you can simply assign it a value.

Comment: @cookertron - it works if you think of it as initializing an array of references/pointers to points. If you tried to do point* p[100], and modify the values, you'd be modifying the pointers. Think of it as java dereferencing the pointer and now you've segfaulted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while you initialized the array, you did not initialize the elements of the array.

On this line you have

```
point[] p = new point[points];
```

So now, p is initialized to an array of points with length `points`

However, you can imagine that in this array, the individual point objects are uninitialized(so all null). Thus, when you call `p[i].x = (float)tx;` you dereference the point object at p[i], but p[i] is not initialized, so you are dereferencing a null pointer.

You are doing the equivalent of

```
point p;
p.x = 5;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I understand now. Like I mentioned above it seems strange to have to initialise the elements after initialising the array. In C++ once you've allocated the memory for an array that's it, the array index points to the position within the memory and the structure points to the offset.

Comment: You're very welcome! I can understand your confusion. 

However, it's a little bit different because we are dealing with an array of Java references, so in C++ syntax, what you would be doing is 

point *p[]

so you can imagine if you did something like p[i].x in that situation you would also get a null reference in c++